# Swift firebase - How to paginate posts by date across different users

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Pagination has been discussed a lot. But I still would like to know if there is a way to `query` posts like 5 at a time according to their `creationDate` across all users. In other words, I would like to display the newest posts in the order or `creationDate` no matter who the posted them. The database structure is the picture below:[image: Immediately under the node "posts" is the userID, then postID]

In the pic above, the level immediately under "posts" is the user ID, like the first user has 7 posts, the second user has only one post. The level under the user ID is the post ID.